# Debugging Childbrowser

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have an external page that works in webkit on an android device.  When I view the page via phonegap's childbrowser plugin the page does not work correctly. How can I debug this childbrowser page? My alerts are not appearing.

Comment: adb logcat would be a start...

Comment: my console.log's are not appearing in logcat

Comment: What version of the ChildBrowser are you using? I've made some updates recently. What page are you trying to view?

Comment: I'm not sure how to identify the ChildBrowser version, but I took a copy from https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ChildBrowserhttp://geomobilesrv.edina.ac.uk/login.html 2 weeks ago to work with phonegap 1.7.0. The page that doesn't work properly is http://geomobilesrv.edina.ac.uk/login.html. But I suppose my question is more general, how do you debug the childbrowser? Should console.log's appear in logcat? Should alerts work?

Comment: ok getting the current version fixed my debugging problem, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to upgrade the childbrowser version, see comments.